# Ruby tries to evaluate variable before opening the variable and gives error because it thinks i gave it as a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, checkbox

well, i think that question sounds bizarre but thats what it is.

```
def omg


  logger.info "checkbox ticked" + params[:attribute].to_s

  @devices   =Device.all
  attributes = params[:attribute]

  logger.info attributes

  @devices.each do |device|

    attributes.each do |x|

      y="device.x.to_s"


      logger.info device.x
      @payload = params[:message] #+ device.x.to_s

    end

    APNS.send_notification(device.token.to_s, @payload)

  end
end
```

the problem is simple but i think i don't know what to do since i m new to ruby.

the problem is in the inside of the nested loop.

> Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"LnVMA3CcDftN42bqpfBESlv5uFMnDVVwtSxkG6pV6QM=", "attribute"=>["last_name", "nickname"], "message"=>"asdf", "commit"=>"checkbox test"}
>   checkbox ticked["last_name", "nickname"]
>   ["last_name", "nickname"]

this is the console log and my parameters

now it runs smooth when i make device.nickname or device.first_name they are stored in my device object.I get my attributes from the checkboxes and i need to send payload according to the checkbox input

it should have evaluate variable and make  device.x  as device.nickname and device.last_name  but it tries to run x as a method. BUT ITS NOT.

how can i bypass this problem.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev how simple, cheers.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev can you point out a good source where i can read these sort of stuffs.Thanks again

Comment: @SergioTulentsev one more thing , you can write it down if you want me to accept it

Comment: You can access the attributes like `devise[x]`

Comment: @databaseGuy: you know, books. :)